# JS Fetch failing to POST JSON with a PHP API backend

Tags: javascript, php, json, xmlhttprequest, fetch-api

I have been trying to connect to my server to send and receive data, but for some reason I can only GET data back, but not POST data. I am using the JS Fetch API, but have also tried using the XMLHttpRequest with similar results. I don't receive any error logs except for the catch error that I create, so any help would be fantastic!

Frontend JS POST Users - **Does not Work**

```js
function setUsers() {
    const data = new FormData(apiform);
    const value = Object.fromEntries(data.entries());
    console.log(value);

    fetch("../backend/api/user/create.php", {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(value),
        mode: "cors",
        credentials: "same-origin",
        headers: {
           "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
    })
    .then((response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
            response.json();
        } else {
            throw new Error("Bad Server Response! Response: " + response.status);
        }
    })
    .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error("ERROR: Failed to set users...");
    });

    return false;
}
```

Backend PHP Create User (AKA create.php. This is what I am calling from the JS side.)

```php
<?php
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST');
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Access-Control-Allow-Headers,
                                        Access-Control-Allow-Credentials,
                                        Content-Type,
                                        Access-Control-Allow-Methods,
                                        Authorization,
                                        X-Requested-With');

  include_once '../../config/Database.php';
  include_once '../../models/User.php';

  $database = new Database();
  $db = $database->connect();

  $user = new User($db);

  $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

  $user->username = $data->username;
  $user->password = $data->password;
  $user->email = $data->email;

  if($user->createUser()) {
    echo json_encode(
      array('message' => 'User Created')
    );
  } else {
    echo json_encode(
      array('message' => 'User Not Created')
    );
  }
?>
```

Backend PHP User class

```php
<?php
    class User {
        private $conn;
        private $table = 'users';
        public $id;
        public $username;
        public $password;
        public $email;

        public function __construct($db) {
            $this->conn = $db;
        }

        public function getAllUsers() {
            $query = 'SELECT * FROM ' . $this->table . ' ORDER BY username ASC;';
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
            $stmt->execute();

            return $stmt;
        }

        public function createUser() {
            $query = 'INSERT INTO ' . $this->table . ' SET username = :username, 
                                                           password = :password, 
                                                           email = :email';
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

            $this->username = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->username));
            $this->password = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->password));
            $this->email = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->email));

            $stmt->bindParam(':username', $this->username);
            $stmt->bindParam(':password', $this->password);
            $stmt->bindParam(':email', $this->email);

            if ($stmt->execute()) {
                return true;
            } else {
                printf("ERROR: %s.\n", $stmt->error);
                return false;
            }
        }
?>
```

UPDATE:
I have tried to use async and await thinking I was using fetch wrong, but that still didn't work. I am beginning to think the problem is more on the apache server side, though I am not sure why because GET works.

Comment: "I don't receive any error logs except for the catch error that I create" — which catch error? You have several.

Comment: What does the Network tab in your browser show? Is the body of the request what you expect? Is the response what you expect?

Comment: "I don't receive any error logs" — Have you tried writing some logging statements into your PHP to figure out what is going on? Where in the PHP does it fail?

Comment: `htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->username));` — `strip_tags` doesn't seem like a good choice for determining what characters are allowed in a username. Nor does stripping them instead of telling the user that the username is invalid. `htmlspecialchars` makes no sense. You're inserting the data into a database, not an HTML document.

Comment: **Danger**: "Not hashing at all" is [an unsuitable hashing algorithm](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php); you need to [take better care](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet) of your users' passwords.

Comment: @Quentin the catch is happening in the JS fetch. I put in some console logs to help find the problem, but I am still stumped. I can see the object being created on the browser side, but it doesn't send with fetch. as far as I can tell, the data doesn't even make it to the `htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->username));`. And for the password not being hashed, that's ok because this is just a test to ensure I can pass data back and forth between the server and the end user. I tried swapping the fetch function with `XMLHttpRequest` and that seemed to get further but I get null values on php side

Answer (score 1):

Found a simple solution and forgot to actually put it on here, but the answer is to add an event object to the frontend JS then use the prevent default function to stop the default handling of forms and prevents the page from refreshing for FireFox, Safari and the like. So it looks like this:

```
function setUser(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    ...
    console.log("Everything else started working...");
}
```

Note: This worked on Chrome with AND without this event object.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add `Content-Type: application/json` for `header`

```
<?php
$data = array("a" => "Apple", "b" => "Ball", "c" => "Cat");
header("Content-Type: application/json");
echo json_encode($data);
```

Result will be in JSON as you need :

[image]

Comment: You are correct the header is essential.  But it appears to me the the OP is already sending the application/json header in the "JS POST Users"

Comment: I am already doing that in my create.php. I do think headers are the issue though. I am just not sure what header or why.